# Vertically center text in a table header

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm new to CSS and HTML and I'm trying to vertically center some text in a table header. At the moment the text is aligned with the top of the table cell. I was unsuccessful with `vertical-align: middle;`, and the only solution seems to be to add `padding-top` to match the space underneath the text. However this is not the best solution because I would like to have the text fit snugly within the table cell. Any ideas are appreciated.

```css
body {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding:0;
}

.mytable {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

.mytable thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  /*padding: 30px;*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mytable tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myWebPage" style="display:block">
  <br><br><br><br>
  <h3>Page title here</h3><br><br><br>

  <table class="mytable" align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><u>Resource</u><br><br><br></th>
        <th><u>Contact</u><br><br><br></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Resource 1<br><br></th>
        <th align="left" width=35%;>999-999-9999<br> <br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Resource 2<br><br></th>
        <th align="left">888-888-8888<br><br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Resource 3<br><br></th>
        <th align="left" width=35%;>777-777-7777<br> <br></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have done it right in your CSS, just remove your `<br>` tags. E.g.

```
<th><u>Resource</u></th>
```

The vertical alignment won't work whilst you're manually inserting lines under your headings.

**Full example**

```css
body {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding:0;
}

.mytable {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

.mytable thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  /*padding: 30px;*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mytable tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myWebPage" style="display:block">
  <br><br><br><br>
  <h3>Page title here</h3><br><br><br>

  <table class="mytable" align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><u>Resource</u></th>
        <th><u>Contact</u></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Resource 1<br><br></td>
        <td align="left" width=35%;>999-999-9999<br> <br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Resource 2<br><br></td>
        <td align="left">888-888-8888<br><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Resource 3<br><br></td>
        <td align="left" width=35%;>777-777-7777<br> <br></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: noted wheres is your The ` <td>` elements are the data containers of the table.

Comment: I copied the OP's original code and fixed the specific issue, although I've edited the HTML to include the td's.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this , why are you put `<br>` and `<td>` to `<th>`

Table `<td>` The  elements are the data containers of the table.
HTML 
 Tag is 
A line break is marked up as follows:

```
This text contains<br>a line break.
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding:0;
}

.mytable {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

.mytable thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  /*padding: 30px;*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mytable tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <h3>Page title here</h3>

  <table class="mytable" align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><u>Resource</u></th>
        <th><u>Contact</u></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Resource 1</td>
        <td align="left" width=35%;>999-999-9999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Resource 2</td>
        <td align="left">888-888-8888</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Resource 3</td>
        <td align="left" width=35%;>777-777-7777</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

learn more about  **html table** https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Define a `height` value for the `th` elements**

Define an explicit (absolute) height for your table header cells (`th`) using *length unit* values (e.g: `65px`), then declare the `vertical-align` rule on these elements.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.mytable {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

.mytable thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  /*padding: 30px;*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* additional */
  height: 65px;
}

.mytable tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myWebPage" style="display:block">
  <br><br><br><br>
  <h3>Page title here</h3><br><br><br>

  <table class="mytable" align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><u>Resource</u></th>
        <th><u>Contact</u></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Resource 1<br><br></th>
        <th align="left" width=35%;>999-999-9999<br> <br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Resource 2<br><br></th>
        <th align="left">888-888-8888<br><br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Resource 3<br><br></th>
        <th align="left" width=35%;>777-777-7777<br> <br></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<br>` tags for layout - that's a no-go! It will mess up whatever you try concerning vertical alignment and top/bottom padding and margins, like in the code in your question.

Erase them all and use top and bottom padding instead.

If still needed, use `vertical-align`,  but in most cases you won't need it. And use the `td` tag for cells in the `tbody`, not `th`.

```css
body {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding:0;
}
#myWebPage > h3 {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.mytable {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

.mytable thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  padding: 30px 0;
  /*padding: 30px;*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mytable tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myWebPage">
  <h3>Page title here</h3>
  <table class="mytable" align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><u>Resource</u></th>
        <th><u>Contact</u></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Resource 1</td>
        <td align="left" width=35%;>999-999-9999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Resource 2</td>
        <td align="left">888-888-8888</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Resource 3</td>
        <td align="left" width=35%;>777-777-7777</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```